# edit the detail of the image

Tags: c#, image, metadata

I'm working with new project, and I need to edit the details of an image in C#, such as tag, comment, authors, etc.

Comment: get the details of an image, then edit it

Comment: I suspect he needs to amend some data associated (in a db table perhaps) with an image... We need more detail here matey...

Comment: Mohamad - Do you mean information that is contained within the JPEG file itself - the MetaData?

Comment: yes, I need to edit the image metadata, Tag, Comment, Authors, Copyright..

Comment: It's tagged with MetaData, so one would assume he's talking about MetaData o_O

Comment: isn't the same? metadata and the details of the picture ?

Comment: Sort of, MetaData and the Details have different information.  The MetaData is a bit more in-depth, although details are included within it; whereas the Details do not include MetaData-specific items, like GPS information.

Comment: I need edit the metadata of an image, exactly the "comment" I want to add comment to the image this is all what I want

Comment: well, now that we finally sorted out what you need, could you please update your question so we can get rid of all the chatty comments please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have taken this code from here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43266/Reading-and-Writing-Photo-Metadata-Programmaticall

Microsoft has a set of tools called Pro Photo Tools, which can be added and referenced to VS.  Reference the DLL to your project, and use similar code to the one provided.

This is a hard-coded method, but it should be very easy to make a small form to take control of it.

```
try
{ 
  var img_path = @"@C:\[PATH TO YOUR IMAGE FILE].jpg";
  var p = (new MetadataPolicyManager()).loadPolicy(@"C:\[PATH TO POLICY FILE]" + 
       @"\Microsoft.PhotoToolboxFoundation.ToolboxPolicy.xml"); 

  imgProxy = new ImageFileProxy(img_path, p); 
  object desc = imgProxy.Data[p.getTagIndex("Description")];
  Console.WriteLine("Description: " + desc.ToString());

  imgProxy.Data[p.getTagIndex("Description")] = "Description modified!"; 
  imgProxy.commit(); 
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{
  // write exception handler 
}
```

Comment: If you only want to edit the Comment, try changing the Keyword "Description" to "Comment".  Can't guarantee that, though.  You could try Googling a bit, I'll give you one more site before I stop Googling things for you.  http://www.andrewdothay.net/blog/2010/08/16/HowToEditMetaDataInsideJPGFilesWithC.aspx